# Fatal error: Call to a member function in the login validation

Tags: codeigniter, models, codeigniter-form-helper

I have the controller file:- login.php

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();  
  }
  function success() {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $errorMsg ="";
    $queryResult = $this->logins->validate($username,$password);
    if($queryResult == TRUE) {
      redirect ('home'); 
    } 
    else {
      $errorMsg ="Invalid Username or Password"; 
      $this->load->view('login',$errorMsg); 
     }
  }
 }
```

view:- login.php

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function validatelogin(){
            var x=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
            var y=document.forms["login"]["passwrd"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            if (y==null || y=="")
            {
                alert("Password field must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            /*if(x!="monisha" && y!="monisha"){
                alert("Username and Password incorrect");
                return false;
            }*/
            return true;  
        }
    </script>
```

the HTML form have:-

```
 <form name="login" id="login" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>login/success" onsubmit="return validatelogin()" method="post">
```

Model file logins.php is having the function, which describes function validate

```
    class Logins extends CI_Model {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function validate($username,$password){
            $this->db->select('username','password');
            $this->db->from('logins');
            $this->db->where('username', $username); 
            $query = $this->db->get('logins');
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $passwrd = $row->password;
                    if($passwrd == $password) { 
                        return TRUE; 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
    }
    }
```

but showing the error:-

Fatal error: Call to a member function validate() on a non-object in this line:-

$queryResult = $this->logins->validate($username,$password);

Answer (score 0):

You aren't loading class "logins"

```
$this->load->library('Logins');
```

Comment: Loaded this $this->load->model('Logins'); in controller constructor

Comment: sorry.. 

function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
         $this->load->model('Logins');
         $this->load->library('Logins');
    }

Comment: got an error like this:- 

Unable to load the requested class: logins

Comment: my bad - Logins is your model, so only load model. BUT: 1) update your code above for others, 2) Read the manual a it - this isn't a tutorial site, these are all very basic questions

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your model

```
   public function __construct() {
        // Connecting Database 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Add your model Class name into **config\autoload.php** file

**$autoload['model'] = array('logins');**

Its working fine for me,Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Load the model named **Logins** before you use it

```
$this->load->model('logins', '', TRUE);
```

or in autoload.php